# How do I add a video file (mp4) into my android application?

Tags: java, android, android-videoview, mp4

I want to be able to add a video I created that automatically starts playing when it's brought up on the screen, so far my code looks like this:

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.button10);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.group_project);
videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();
```

Currently nothing happens when I click and go on that screen. It plays sound when I used media player but I really want to add this video. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very important the use of `setOnPreparedListener()` method, and be sure to have a video called `group_project.mp4` inside `/raw` folder.

```
  final VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.group_project);
    videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoview.start();    
            }
        });
```

Read the documentation:

> A MediaPlayer object must first enter the Prepared state before
>   playback can be started. There are two ways (synchronous vs.
>   asynchronous) that the Prepared state can be reached: either a call to
>   prepare() (synchronous) which transfers the object to the Prepared
>   state once the method call returns, or a call to prepareAsync()
>   (asynchronous) which first transfers the object to the Preparing state
>   after the call returns (which occurs almost right way) while the
>   internal player engine continues working on the rest of preparation
>   work until the preparation work completes. When the preparation
>   completes or when prepare() call returns, the internal player engine
>   then calls a user supplied callback method, onPrepared() of the
>   OnPreparedListener interface, if an OnPreparedListener is registered
>   beforehand via
>   [setOnPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener))(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener).

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.button10);
MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.group_project);
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.start();
```

Comment: that code doesn't closes the app with an unknown error, I've tried placing it everywhere, presumably it goes in on create...

Answer (score 0):

Try this before doing videoview.start() to ensure is ready.

```
videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        videoview.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: apparently the setonprepared listener is not applicable for the argument

Comment: I forgot to write @Override for onPrepared but my answer was right, just a small typo. Compare.

Comment: My answer should be marked as correct as well. Tnx :)